# PHP spam filter idea not working but logic is sound

Tags: php, post, logic

So I run a chan based on kusaba imageboards.

I get a ridiculous amount of spam. The spam is coming from people who run scripts, and are somehow even bypassing the Captcha system. Sometimes it contains text, usually its just a new thread with an image. Rather than ban them every 32 minutes, I am trying a new thing: if an image is being posted with a message, it should see if the message is blank. if the message is blank, exit with an error code (and therefore not posting)

the code I wrote is here: `

```
if isset($_POST['message']) && isset($_FILES['imagefile']) {
        if ($_FILES['imagefile'] != NULL && $_FILES['message'] == NULL) {
            exitWithErrorPage('Please enter some text with your image to prevent spam abuse.');
    }
}
```

for some reason I am getting this error: 
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ISSET, expecting '(' in /home/content/61/11420661/html/board.php on line 106

Comment: `if` lacks parentheses: if (...) { ... }. BTW, the error message could hardly have been more explicit: "unexpected ISSET, expecting ("...

Answer (score 1):

It's a syntax error:

```
if isset($_POST['message']) && isset($_FILES['imagefile'])
```

should be

```
if (isset($_POST['message']) && isset($_FILES['imagefile']))
```

Comment: thanks to all who posted. It is working now. Putting on some finishing touches so that it only affects new threads and not replies. oh boy.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a set of parenthesis around your first `if` statement.

```
if(isset($_POST['message']) && isset($_FILES['imagefile'])) {
  ^                                                       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the ( after if as well as the closing one.
try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['message']) && isset($_FILES['imagefile'])) {
        if ($_FILES['imagefile'] != NULL && $_FILES['message'] == NULL) {
            exitWithErrorPage('Please enter some text with your image to prevent spam abuse.');
    }
}
```

Comment: A great way to combat spam is to use a hidden field in your form. Humans can;t see it but spam-bots will and they will enter a value for it more often than not. Just check for a value in your postvars and if one exists, you've got spam. Example:

<input type="text" name="badguy" style="display: none;">